# How to show recyclerview inside child tab of the fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am trying to show the the list retrieved from the firestore database in child tab TODAY and WEEK as shown in the image shared, but I am getting error at this line of the code.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(c));
```

I tried to figure out but nothing possible solution till now ,  I have shared the code below, Please assist me where I am wrong and correct me. Thank You.

[screenshot of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDOsN.jpg)

```
public class TodaysFixturesFragment
        extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference PostsRef = db.collection("posts");
    private FirebaseAuth mauth;
    private PostsAdapter adapter;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    private Button commentsbutton;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RelativeLayout mParent;



    private String mUserID;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //just change the fragment_dashboard
        //with the fragment you want to inflate
        //like if the class is HomeFragment it should have R.layout.home_fragment
        //if it is DashboardFragment it should have R.layout.fragment_dashboard

        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profile_pic");

        mauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUserID = mauth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
       // Query query = PostsRef.whereEqualTo("post_author_id", mUserID).whereEqualTo("l3", true);
        Query query = PostsRef;
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(c);
/*
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<PostsModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<PostsModel>()
                .setQuery(query, PostsModel.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new PostsAdapter(options);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_mw_pending);
        // recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(c));

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        mParent =view.findViewById(R.id.relative_home1);*/




        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mwpending, null);


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }


}
```

Logcat Details

```
Process: com.ramneekkashyap.blogapplication.blogapp2, PID: 6115
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.ramneekkashyap.blogapplication.blogapp2.adapters.PostsAdapter.startListening()' on a null object reference
        at com.ramneekkashyap.blogapplication.blogapp2.TodaysFixturesFragment.onStart(TodaysFixturesFragment.java:86)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2632)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:915)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1696)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:299)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:235)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24955)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7149)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:743)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:99)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1882)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:813)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24955)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24955)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7149)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24955)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24955)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7149)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:743)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:99)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1882)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:813)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24955)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24955)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24955)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7149)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24955)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7149)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24955)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7149)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24955)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7149)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24955)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7149)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:1029)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24955)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3338)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2366)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1927)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8558)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6115 SIG: 9
Process 6115 terminated.
```

Comment: please share your logCat

Comment: @AlirezaBideli logcat is shared , please assist thank you

Comment: Your Error is NullPointerException you don't  initialize your adapter  . I am wonder that is so clear in your logCat . In the first line of your logCat ,the line that your exception heppened is printed.

Comment: initialize your PostsAdapter in your onCreateView .onStart executed after onCreateView for more information i recommoned you to see this link [android Fragment LifeCycle](https://www.journaldev.com/9266/android-fragment-lifecycle)